# Wordpress section background - responsive auto-scaling?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress site and I have a section background set. I used an image with 1920px width. On my 1366px screen the image is not scaling, but is cut-off from the right by the pixel difference. Any way (css?) to make the image scale automatically according to the screen size?
Site url: http://www.imprero.com/wordpress/graffitx/
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The background size must be contained so that it will automatically fit. 
Insert this to the background you are talking about: "background-size: contain;"

Comment: This works on browser's code inspector. I'm not yet great in identifying the complex css selector path. What would it be in this case? Thx.

Comment: What do you mean what would it be in this case? What did you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
element{ 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```